# About the existence of a partition to a partially ordered set $A$.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Let $A$ be a countable set equipped with a partial order $\prec$. We all know that there are subsets $C\subset A$ with the property that the order $\prec$ in $C$ is total.  In other words, any two elements $a$ and $b$ in $C$ are comparable.

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be the collection of all subsets $C$ of $A$ that are totally ordered.

> **Question 1**: Is it true $A=\displaystyle\bigcup_{C\in\mathscr{C}}C$?

Denote by $\mathscr{D}$ a any subcolection $\mathscr{D}\subset \mathscr{C}$   such that for all $C_1,C_2\in\mathscr{D}$ we have empty intersection $C_1\cap C_2=\emptyset$.

> **Question 2**: There is a subcollection $\mathscr{D}$ as described above such that $A=\displaystyle\bigcup_{C\in\mathscr{D}}C$?

I know these questions seem intuitive but I'd be happy with some demonstration of elementary set theory either by reduction to absurdity or not

Thank's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They answer to the first question is trivially *yes*, since every singleton is linearly ordered.

**Revised to match edited question:**

The answer to the second question is also trivially *yes*: let $\mathscr{D}=\{\{a\}:a\in A\}$.

Comment: If $\mathscr{D}$ consist of just one singleton were is the contradiction? Can you give an another counter example?

Comment: @Elias: Suppose that $A=\{0,1\}$ with either of the two possible partial orders, and $\mathscr{D}=\{\{0\}\}$. Clearly $A\ne\biguplus_{C\in\mathscr{D}}$.

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake of mine. I've edited my question. Thank's.

Comment: @Elias: I’ve updated my answer to match.

Comment: If we assume further that the subcollection $\mathscr{D}$ does not have any set as elements of the form $\{a\}$ with $a$ in $A$?.  The proof does not seem trivial.

Comment: @Elias: It’s not always true if you make that further assumption. Remember, the relation of equality is a partial order, so it may be that the only subsets of $A$ that are linearly ordered are the singletons.